# Order email sent to customer but displays "customer not notified" in order comments section in Magento in admin panel

Tags: magento

I have implemented 2 payment system in my website. Once the admin submit shipment, then the status is automatically changed to dispatched and the customer receives an email.

But in order comments section it is displaying as "Customer not notified" .

Can you please help me why these kind of issues are happening in Magento 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not set the notification template for that status.

1) Go to:

System -> Order Statuses

2) Find the "dispatched" status

3) In the options select order status notification

Cheers

Comment: I can't get this System -> Order Statuses in magento 2.Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 "Order Status" is located in Stores -> Settings -> Order Status

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).